# RubyOnRails how to create form for ransacker method with arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

I have a custom ransacker method called score

```
  ransacker :score, args: [:parent, :number_one :number_two] do |parent, args|
   (parent.table[:id] + parent.table[:id]) / (number_one + number_two)
  end
```

here number_one and number_two are arguments. how to create input form for this method with 2 ARGS in view?

Comment: https://bclennox.com/searching-json-columns-in-postgres-with-ransack might help. While ransack is very flexible and very functional you may have to build some of this by hand.

Comment: @enngineersmnky Yes, I guess I need to do trial and error. maybe they can be accepted as an array

Comment: hi, @engineersmnky I still did not find an answer, do you have any idea how can I get the form to accept args for ransackers in views?